# ¿Se puede asignar un nombre de forma dinámica a un data.frame?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando crear un informe reproducible, para ello necesitaría crear el nombre de algunos data.frame de forma dinámica, voy a intentar explicarlo:

```
tipopartida <- Gasto
ejercicio <- '2021'
```

NombreDataFrame como una concatenación de `tipopartida` y `ejercicio`

Lo que pretendo, no sé si es la forma adecuada, es poder reutilizar código R para procesar consultas de varios ejercicios de forma automática. Es decir, en lugar de tener un script R para cada ejercicio, utilizar sólo uno creando de forma dinámica el nombre de los objetos.

Saludos,
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola José  creo que esto te puede servir por lo que entiendo deseas crear el nombre un data.frame tomando en cuanta el valor de dos variables concatenadas te muestro un ejemplos

```
var1<-"perro"
var2<-"gato"
df<-data.frame()
assign(paste(var1,var2,sep=""),df)
class(perrogato)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Es importante que antes crees un data.frame y ya después le cambies el valor con los datos que deseas.

Comment: hola Rubén, gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciona `Error: objeto 'perrogato' no encontrado`

Comment: He encontrado este fragmento, pero no logro adaptarlo ```for(i in 1:3) {assign(paste("x_", i), i)```

Comment: Hola Jose Carlos omití agregar en el código de assign(paste(var1,var2,sep=""),df), la parte de df ya modifique la respuesta deberia funcionar

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Rubén